# Подскажите, как синтаксически правильно проверить условием response.status?

Tags: javascript

```
 Есть фрагмент кода. Подскажите, где и как проверять условием response.status? Мне нужно указать, что если response.status не равен 200, то...



const postData = async (url, data) => {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
            headers: {
              'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: data
        });
        return await res.json();
      };
    
      postData('http://localhost:3000/requests', json)
      .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          showThanksModal(message.success);
          statusMessage.remove(); //удаляем спиннэр
      })
      .catch(() => {
        showThanksModal(message.failure);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        form.reset();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const postData = async (url, data) => {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
            headers: {
              'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: data
        });
        
           if (res.status == 200) {
           // your code
        throw new Error('error');
    }
        
        return await res.json();
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Корректнее если проверить статус так

```
  if (res.status == 200) {
    return res.json();
  } else {
    throw new Error(res.status); // добавьте деталей сообщения
  }
```